# Firebase cloud function - get documentby provided field name

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When my client makes a call to https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/getWebsiteIdByName/mywebsite, I want the following firebase function to be called and return a document with the matching name. I've written the function below but keep getting the error: `Error: could not handle the request`. How can I fix this? My code is as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.getWebsiteIdByName = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
  let websiteName = req.url.split("/");
  websiteName = websiteName[websiteName.length - 1];
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const website = admin.firestore().collection('websites', (ref: any) => ref.where('name', '==', websiteName).limit(1)).get();
  return website.then(function (response: any) {
    if (response[0].data()) {
      res.end(`{ "websiteId": "${response[0].data()['id']}" }`);
    } else {
      res.end(`{ "websiteId": null }`);
    }
    console.log('Request successful!');
  }).catch((error: any) => console.log('Request failed: ', error));
});
```

**Attempt 2**

```
exports.getWebsiteIdByName = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
  let websiteName = req.url.split("/");
  websiteName = websiteName[websiteName.length - 1];
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const website = admin.firestore().collection('websites', (ref: any) => ref.where('name', '==', websiteName).limit(1)).get();
  return website.then(function (response: any) {
    if(response.empty) {
      res.end(`{ "websiteName": null }`);
    } else {
      res.end(`{ "websiteName": ${JSON.stringify(response.docs[0].get())}`);
    }
    console.log('Request successful!');
  }).catch((error: any) => console.log('Request failed: ', error));
});
```

Comment: Why did you put the where clause inside collection method? whereas it is not how the documentation recommend

Comment: The method is `firestore().collection('collection_name').where('field','comparison','value_to_compare').get().then(snapshot=>{}).catch()`

Comment: @SagarV thanks, two questions: 1) how would I limit it to one record, 2) how would I access the websiteName in that one record that was been pulled.

Comment: Have posted attempt 2

Comment: What does the functions log say in the console?  Sounds like it's generating an error.

Comment: Also, why are you specifying the type of everything as `any`?  That defeats the purpose of typescript.  Everything should have a dedicated type.

Comment: @methuselah I recommend you to go through the corresponding documentation for a complete understanding https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data. fyi, you can use `.limit(1)` after `.where()` and either `forEach` or `snapshot.docs[0].data().websiteName` to get website name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually, I was returning a QuerySnapshot, so it had to be processed differently.

```
exports.getWebsiteIdByName = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
  let websiteName = req.url.split("/");
  websiteName = websiteName[websiteName.length - 1];
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const website = admin.firestore().collection('websites', (ref: any) => ref.where('name', '==', websiteName).limit(1)).get();
  return website.then(function (response: any) {
    if (response.empty) {
      res.end(`{ "websiteId": null }`);
    } else {
      res.end(`{ "websiteId": ${JSON.stringify(response.docs[0].data()['id'])} }`);
    }
    console.log('Request successful!');
  }).catch((error: any) => console.log('Request failed: ', error));
});
```